# Django - Nested loops and template rendering with Forms

Tags: django, python-3.x, forms, templates, render

Is there a way to set a variable after a return statement?

I am trying to execute a for loop with a if clause. At first the if clause is False and after the for loop is executed completely it should render a template with a form and then set the variable to True afterwards. Then the for loop gets executed again but this time it should execute the if statement and submit the Form which is something like ("Are you sure?" and then Continue or Cancel). I tried it with using nested loops (for loop inside a while loop) but the return render statement to render the template with the request is not working with setting the variable afterwards.

This is my `views.py`

```
def file_upload(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
            # Wenn CSV Datei valide ist --> Datei hochladen
            csv_file = request.FILES['file']
            csv_file.seek(0)
            decoded_file = csv_file.read().decode('utf-8').splitlines()
            reader = csv.reader(decoded_file)
            updated_list = list()
            created_list = list()
            s = False
            form2 = ConfirmationForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            while (True):
                for row in reader:
                    count += 1
                    try:
                        datet = datetime.now().date()
                        datum = datet.strftime("%d.%m.%Y")
                        row[7] = datum
                        row[8] = str(request.user)
                        #d = [row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4]]
                        dataset1 = CSV5.objects.filter(gebaeudebereich=row[0],
                                                         gebaeudenummer=row[1], ebene=row[2],
                                                         raum=row[3], dose=row[4])#.values_list("gebaeudebereich", "gebaeudenummer",
                                                         #                                       "ebene", "raum", "dose")
                        dataset2 = CSV5.objects.filter(switch_ip=row[5], switch_port=row[6])#.values_list("switch_ip", "switch_port")
                        ds1 = CSV5.objects.values_list("gebaeudebereich", "gebaeudenummer", "ebene",
                                                                          "raum", "dose")
                        ds2 = CSV5.objects.values_list("switch_ip", "switch_port")
                        #print("ds1: ", ds1)
                        print("count: ", count)
                        print("dataset1: ", dataset1)
                        print("dataset2: ", dataset2)
                        print("dataset1: ", dataset1.exists())
                        print("dataset2: ", dataset2.exists())
                        print("s: ", s)

                        if (dataset1.exists() and not dataset2.exists()):
                            #instance = get_object_or_404(CSV5, id=count)
                            print("Fall 1")
                            ins = CSV5.objects.filter(gebaeudebereich=row[0],
                                                         gebaeudenummer=row[1], ebene=row[2],
                                                         raum=row[3], dose=row[4])
                            #liste.append(ins.values_list())
                            #print("liste: ", liste)
                            print ("instance: ", ins)
                            if form2.is_valid() and s == True:
                                ins.update(switch_ip=row[5], switch_port=row[6], datum = row[7], akteur = row[8])
                            else:
                                updated_list.append(ins)
                            updated_obj += 1
                        elif not dataset1.exists() and dataset2.exists():
                            print("Fall 2")
                            ins = CSV5.objects.filter(switch_ip=row[5], switch_port=row[6])
                            print("instance: ", ins)
                            if form2.is_valid() and s == True:
                                ins.update(gebaeudebereich = row[0], gebaeudenummer = row[1], ebene = row[2], raum = row[3],
                                           dose = row[4], datum = row[7], akteur = row[8])
                            else:
                                updated_list.append(ins.values_list())
                                print("dat2: ", dataset2)
                            updated_obj += 1
                        elif (dataset1.exists() and dataset2.exists()):
                            print("Fall 3")
                            #liste.append(dataset1)
                            #print("liste: ", liste)
                            duplicate_obj += 1
                        elif not (dataset1.exists() and dataset2.exists()):
                            print("Fall 4")
                            if form2.is_valid() and s == True:
                                ins = CSV5.objects.get_or_create(id=CSV5.objects.count() + 1, gebaeudebereich=row[0],
                                                             gebaeudenummer=row[1], ebene=row[2],
                                                             raum=row[3], dose=row[4], switch_ip=row[5], switch_port=row[6],
                                                             datum=row[7], akteur=row[8])
                                created_list.append(ins)
                                ins.save()
                            created_obj += 1
                    except IndexError:
                        print("IndexError")
                        break
                    except IntegrityError:
                        duplicate_obj += 1
                        print("IntegrityError")


                if s != False:
                    messages.success(request, "objects created: %s " % created_obj)
                    messages.success(request, "objects updated: %s " % updated_obj)
                    messages.success(request, "duplicate objects: %s " % duplicate_obj)
                    break

                elif s == False:
                    messages.success(request, "Einträge die neu hinzugefügt werden: %s " % created_list)
                    messages.success(request, "Einträge die überschrieben werden: %s " % updated_list)
                    messages.success(request, "Duplikate: %s " % duplicate_obj)

                    form = ConfirmationForm()
                    return render(request, "appp/confirmation.html", {'form' : form})

                s = True

    form = UploadFileForm()
    return render(
        request, "appp/file_upload.html", {"form": form}
    )
```

Here is my ConfirmationForm:

```
class ConfirmationForm(forms.Form):
    class Meta:
        model = CSV5
        fields = ('gebaeudebereich', 'gebaeudenummer', 'ebene', 'raum', 'dose',
                  'switch_ip', 'switch_port', 'datum', 'akteur',)
```

`confirmation.html`

```
{% extends 'appp/base.html' %}
{% block body %}

<h2>Bestätigung</h2>

{% if user.is_authenticated %}

    {% if messages %}
<ul class="messages">
    {% for message in messages %}
    <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit" onclick="return confirm('Sollen die angezeigten Daten in der Datenbank gespeicher werden?')">Speichern</button>
</form>


<a href = "{% url 'appp:index' %}">
<button>Cancel</button>
</a>

{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

And finally my `models.py`

```
class CSV5(models.Model):
    gebaeudebereich = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    gebaeudenummer = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    ebene = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    raum = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    dose = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    switch_ip = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    switch_port = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    datum = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    akteur = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("gebaeudebereich", "gebaeudenummer", "ebene", "raum", "dose"), ("switch_ip", "switch_port"))
```

So the for loop iterates through every entry and since s is False. It is doing the validation without actually querying the DB. After the for loop has been executed I use a ConfirmationForm where the data that is about to be changed is displayed to the user and then s is set to True. However because I use a return statement, setting the variable to True is not working.
Any help would be appreciated.